# Flask + React, run without `npm run build` every time

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

If I have the Flask `App.py` pointed to the `frontend/build` folder, the frontend works fine currently, but I have to rebuild with `npm run build` every time I make changes to frontend code

`app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='frontend/build')`

I tried changing this to

`app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='frontend/public')` where the source `index.html` resides, but this did not work

Is there a way I can run the React frontend without building it every time? For debugging purposes, not for release.

Thanks,

Comment: hot-reload? watch-mode build?

Comment: Watch = rebuild on every file save (still time consuming to build, only saves me from entering the command)

Comment: Hot Reload = if I am reading correctly is for server side loading, but I just want to develop the frontend.  I dont see why it shouldn't work, Javascript doesn't need to be built or compiled to run

Comment: modern tools can keep a cache for later builds, so subsequent builds are incremental, rebuilding only what changed, which is significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can set another folder path in `static_folder` for development purposes.
You can use a variable for indicating development mode, and change the directory path in that case. It can be something like:

```
static_folder="dev/path" if is_dev_mode else "prod/path"
```